# Notify me when a socket binds, like inotify does for files

Tags: linux, sockets, gdb

I am interested in finding out when things SSH into my boxen to create a reverse tunnel.  Currently I'm using a big hack - just `lsof` with a few lines of script.  So my goal is to see when a socket calls bind() and, ideally, get the port it binds to (it's listening locally since it's a reverse tunnel) and the remote host that I would be connecting to.  My `lsof` hack is basically fine, except I don't get instant notifications and it's rather... hacky :)

This is easy for files; once a file does just about anything, inotify can tell me in Linux.  Of course, other OSs have a similar capability.

I'm considering simply tailing the SSHD logs and parsing the output, but my little "tunnel monitor" daemon needs to be able to figure out the state of the tunnels at any point in time, even if it hasn't been running the whole time SSHD has.

I have a pretty evil hack I've been considering as well.  It's a script that invokes GDB on `/usr/sbin/sshd`, then sets a breakpoint on `bind`.  Then it runs it with the options `-d -p <listening port>` -- Running a separate SSHD for these tunnels is fine.  Then it waits for that breakpoint to get hit, and uses GDB's input to get the remote hosts's IP address and the local IP on which SSH is now listening.  Again, that's text parsing and opens some other issues.

Is there a "good" way to do this?

Comment: Interesting question! I'll keep an eye on it. BTW: Thumbs up for your ludicrous hack-around! ;-)

Comment: Can you please post your code, seems very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I would use SystemTap for a problem like this.  You can use it to probe the kernel to see when a bind is done by any process on the system.  http://sourceware.org/systemtap/